# How to prevent 'NoneType' object to thrown error

Tags: python

I'm using a library written by some folk in Google to interact with their Apps service. For some reason the code doesn't fully work and I end up getting the following error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

or

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

accordingly to the fact I do use a wrapper function that is meant to check whether the element has a property called text.

This is the function they wrote.

```
def safeElementText(element):
  if hasattr(element, 'text'):
     return element.text
  return ''
```

I'm not a real expert in Python, but to me it seems that element already arrives as NoneType. However, there is no chance for me to change their code, so I though that by modifying the code in this way

```
def safeElementText(element):
  if element is None:
    return 'ssss'
  if hasattr(element, '__getitem__'):
     return 'aaa'
  if hasattr(element, 'text'):
     return element.text
  return ''
```

I would have been able to sort out the problem. This is not the case. Does this mean that a NoneType cannot be intercepted at all?

Comment: The function you are looking at works just fine for `None`. What is the traceback you are seeing? I don't think you are understanding the problem you are seeing quite correctly.

Comment: `hasattr(None, 'text')` will return `False` just fine, for example. The `TypeError` is caused by `None[...]` item access.

Comment: Quite surprised that code isn't `return getattr(element, 'text', '')` if written by Google... :)

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SitesFeedSummary.py", line 70, in <module>
    safeElementText(entry.preferred_domain)[:30],entry.indexed.text[:5],safeElementText(entry.geolocation)[:10])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
mac-pro:webmastertools andreamoro$